# Initialize a managed array of thread

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I have success to compile the following code but I have to make an array of thread out of it.

```
Form1^ form1obj = gcnew Form1();
Thread^ bfcaller = gcnew Thread(
gcnew ThreadStart(  form1obj, &Form1::bruteforce  ));
bfcaller->Start();
```

I got errors by the making it array like this:

```
array<Form1^>^ form1obj = gcnew array<Form1^>(25);
array<Thread^>^ bfcaller = gcnew array<Thread^>[25];

for (int counter = 0; counter < 25; counter++)
{
    bfcaller[counter] = gcnew Thread( gcnew ThreadStart(form1obj, &Form1::bruteforce));
}
```

Where do I did it wrong? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several syntax mistakes in your code.

```
   gcnew array<Thread^>[25];
```

Don't use square brackets, use (25)

```
   gcnew ThreadStart(form1obj, &Form1::bruteforce)
```

First argument is wrong, it must be a reference to a Form1 instance, not an array of forms since bruteforce() is a method of Form1.  Maybe you meant form1obj[counter].

Comment: Thank you for your post. It compiled perfectly. Like you said, the first argument must be form1obj[counter]. Thanks again (i have googling for this problem 2 days already, lol)